# How to convert localytics phonegap plugin to ionic3

Tags: angular, cordova, plugins, ionic3, phonegap

We have made application in ionic version-1 in that we are using localytics phonegap plugin which is working fine in our ionic version 1.Now we migrate our app in ionic 3. Unfortunately plugin is not updated for ionic3.

So can you please help us how to convert that plugin which works in our ionic3 app.

Thanks